# Firebase TestLab on IOS - upload invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

Following the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/ios/firebase-console#compress-the-test-files-for-upload, I try to test my app with Firebase TestLab

However, I get the issue: **"Upload invalid: Uploaded zip files must contain a single .xctestrun file and the contents of the DerivedData/Build/Products directory."**

I do .zip with exactly these file (Runner_iphoneos12.1-arm64e.xctestrun) and directory (Debug-iphoneos) since there are no other files or directories in my customized DerivedData/Build/Products

I have made many attempts to find a solution, including Product/Clean, Xcode restart, cleaning of my customized DerivedData/Build/Products - but with no success

Do you have any ideas what it could be?

By the way, I work in Xcode 10.1 and my project is on Flutter, if this make any difference

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I am also experiencing issues using the `fastlane` plugin. I suspect this has something to do with the way Xcode 10.1 packages the schemas into the `.xctestrun` file.

Comment: Same here. Regular project (Swift, not flutter). XCode 10.1

Comment: @user1512464 we are discussing this issue directly with developers' team on Slack channel. So, hopefully, it will be resolved soon.

Comment: Hey Dev its working here.

Comment: Did you find a solution @MarySeleznova ? I still have this problem in 2023 :(

Comment: Have the same issue still in 2023. The only workaround is to build the .zip file locally and then upload to TestLab manually. When I go through gcloud it fails, I lose .xctestrun file.